# How to query metadata of an OData action?

Tags: apache, rest, url, odata, olingo

I want to query metadata of an OData action in order to find out, which parameters are expected and how they are named.

I am aware, that I can figure this out by typing `link-to-service-root.com/service.svc/$metadata`. However, in this case I have to dig through the complete metadata output.

Instead I am looking for an elegant way to do this. Maybe there exists a query `link-to-service-root.com/service.svc/$metadata/Action('Namespace.NameOfAction')` (inspired by blog post on [queryable odata metadata](http://www.odata.org/blog/queryable-odata-metadata/)).

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Action (or Actions) from the EDM and then play with parameters. Let me know if this helps.

```
    String serviceRoot = "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/";
    EdmMetadataRequest request = ODataClientFactory.getClient().getRetrieveRequestFactory().getMetadataRequest(serviceRoot);
    ODataRetrieveResponse<Edm> response = request.execute();
    Edm edm = response.getBody();
    List<EdmAction> edmActions = edm.getSchemas().get(0).getActions(); //get the first schema
    for (EdmAction action : edmActions) {
        System.out.println("Action name: " + action.getName());
        List<String> actionParamNames = action.getParameterNames();
        System.out.println("Parameters: ");
        for (String actionParamName : actionParamNames) {
            EdmParameter param = action.getParameter(actionParamName);
            System.out.println(param.getName() + " (" + param.getType().getName() + ")");
             //getMaxLength //getPrecision //isNullable //isCollection //etc.   
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------");
    }
```

Comment: How to get functions and actions bound to specific entity ? e.g. How to list all actions and functions bound to customer entity?